# Rails 3.1 mail encoding issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a Payment mailer class that creates email:

```
class PaymentMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  include LocaleWrapper
  helper :application

  def payment_notification(payment)
    host = payment.try(:host)
    @payment = payment
    @user = payment.user
    using_locale((@user && @user.locale) || I18n.locale) {
      attachments["#{set_default_domain_name_from(host)}_receipt_#{Time.now.strftime("%Y_%m_%d")}.pdf"] = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
        render_to_string(pdf: "#{set_default_domain_name_from(host)}_receipt_#{Time.now.strftime("%Y_%m_%d")}.pdf", template: filtre_mail_template_by_host(host), layout: "pdf.html"))
      headers['Precedence'] = 'bulk'
      mail(:to => @user.email, :subject => I18n.t("mailer_subjects.payment_completed"), :from => "no-reply@#{set_default_domain_name_from(host)}") do |format|
        format.text(:content_transfer_encoding => "base64")
        format.html
     end
    }
  end
```

I have observer method that saves email in the database:

```
 def delivered_email(email)
  Rails.logger.info email.inspect
  html_body = (email.multipart? ? email.html_part : email).body.to_s
  text_body = (email.multipart? ? email.text_part : email).body.to_s
  outgoing_mail = OutgoingMail.new({
    :to => email.to.join(', '),
    :from => email.from.join(', '),
    :subject => email.subject.to_s,
    :sent_at => email.date,
    :html_body => html_body,
    :text_body => text_body,
    :multipart => email.multipart?,
  })
  outgoing_mail.save
  save_attachments(email, outgoing_mail)
end
```

Problem is with multipart email's plain text version, which returns ASCII 8bit string and mysql throws Mysql2::Error: Incorrect string value error.

```
(rdb:1) text_body
"N\x16\xA7\x93*.~\x8A\xF2\xA2\xEA\xDC\xA2{k\x89\xBB\xAD\x8A\x89\xD2y\xEA]}\xABmi\xC8fz{_\xA2\xBAZ\xCAg\xA7\xB5\xD7\xADj)l"
(rdb:1) text_body.encoding
#<Encoding:ASCII-8BIT>
```

I have tried using #force_encoding method, but there is no success:

```
(rdb:1) text_body.force_encoding("UTF-8")
"N\u0016\xA7\x93*.~\x8A\xF2\xA2\xEAܢ{k\x89\xBB\xAD\x8A\x89\xD2y\xEA]}\xABmi\xC8fz{_\xA2\xBAZ\xCAg\xA7\xB5\u05EDj)l"
```

Why am i getting ASCII 8bit string instead of UTF-8?

Comment: Did you have `encoding: utf8` in database.yml ? Did you make `rake db:create` ?

Comment: yes i did both things!

Comment: What does this method do, `save_attachments`?